# Userform combobox not populating on initialize

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have a user form with three comboboxes and one text box that I would like to populate with named ranges or public variables.  I am working in Excel 2010 on Windows.  Here is what I have:
First I run through some code that converts one worksheet into a new configuration.  I then call the userform which will set up the variables necessary to update the worksheet further.  I have done this on a Mac and it works, but I am transitioning this from the mac to a windows server.  I thought this would be the easy part but it in not working for some reason.

Here is the code for the userform.

```
Public KorS As String
Public ActivityID As String
Public Stage As String
Public varsaveme As String


Private Sub ufStageDt_Initialize()

AD = varsaveme & ".xls"
duh = KorS

Set Me.tbAdName.Text = duh
Set UserForm1.Caption = AD

'Set Me.cmbLowDt.List = "AnnDt"
Set Me.cmbHighDt.List = "AnnDt"
Set Me.cmbStage.List = "Stage"
Me.cmbLowDt.List = "AnnDt"

End Sub
```

The public variables are present in the code on the worksheet.

Here is the code that I used on the Mac.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Ad = varsaveme & ".xls"

duh = KorS

tbAdName.Text = varsaveme
UserForm.Caption = Ad


cmbLowDt.List = Range("AnnDt").Value
cmbHighDt.List = Range("AnnDt").Value
cmbStage.List = Range("Stage").Text

End Sub
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I am using the ufStageDt.Show command in the vba script to bring up the userform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Set` won't work, so eliminate that. Also, `List` expects an array. For a single hard-coded item, use `Additem`.

```
Me.cmbHighDt.Additem "AnnDt"
```

EDIT: "AnnDt" is a named range:

```
Me.cmbHighDt.List = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("AnnDt"))
```

EDIT2: For dates:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i As Long
With Me.cmbHighDt
    .List = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("AnnDt"))
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        .List(i) = Format(.List(i), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    Next i

    'to get it back to a date
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = DateValue(.List(0))
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: AnnDt is a named range.  How would I get the named range in instead of a single item?

Comment: I have it working with one caveat.  One of the named ranges is a date range.  When I put it in the combobox, it displays the numeric value of the date.  Do I have to format the date field somehow?  The range is formatted as a date.

Comment: I went back to it, building on what you had given me.  I added me.cmbHighDt.list = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Source").Range("AnnDt").Value) and it works.  Not sure why but it does.

Comment: So it does. Interesting!